# Rust tonic and prost_types conversion

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, grpc, rust-tonic, prost

I'm using [tonic](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic) framework, a rust grpc server implementation. In the generated rust code from the proto file, I have a struct which has a field:

```
#[prost(message, optional, tag="3")]
pub data: ::core::option::Option<::prost_types::Value>,
```

generated from a protobuff field:

```
google.protobuf.Value data = 3;
```

I can't seem to find a way to init `data` which is type `prost_types::Value` by converting a struct I have. I'm doing something like:

```
prost_types::Value::try_from(myOwnsStructVar)
```

But it does not work. Anyone have used `prost_types` lib before and know how to encode/convert to `prost_types::Value`

`myOwnsStructVar` is a type struct. I need to convert it to `prost_types::Struct` So then I can do:

```
prost_types::value::Kind::StructValue(myOwnsStructVarAfterConversiontToProstStruct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just from looking at [the docs](https://docs.rs/prost-types/latest/prost_types/struct.Value.html), we can see that `Value` is a struct with a single public field `kind` which is of type `Option<Kind>`. The docs say that if this field is `None` then that indicates an error. If you look at the [docs for `Kind`](https://docs.rs/prost-types/latest/prost_types/value/enum.Kind.html), then it's apparent this is where the actual data is stored. So if you want to initialize something of type `Value` then you'd want to do something like the following, substituting in the appropriate variant of `Kind` for your use case:

```rs
Value {
    kind: Some(Kind::NumberValue(10.0f64))
}
```

The reason that your `try_from` solution didn't work is because there are no `TryFrom` implementations for `Value` other than the default blanket implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a struct that I want to assign it to `data`.  ` prost_types::value::Kind::StructValue(myOwnStructVar)`I need to convert it to `prost_types::Struct` which is gonna be hard because cause its `BTreeMap<::prost::alloc::string::String, Value>`. Any idea how?

Comment: @NoorThabit Similar to `Value`, `prost_types::Struct` has a public field called `fields` of that type, so you can just do `prost_types::Struct { fields: my_btree_map }`. If you're not familiar with structurally initializing Rust types then I would check out the relevant sections of [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. This would be a solution but its not ideal, cause i have to populate the map manually.

Comment: Ah I think I understand better what you were asking now. Looking for some `serde` extension similar to the crate you mentioned here is probably the way to go to make that conversion as painless as possible.